# Changing Meta Title in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

I am trying to change the meta title in Wordpress (overriding the WP page title). I have managed to change the title up in the tab in the browser, but it will not change in a link preview.

I am only trying to change one meta title on one page that has a PHP page template

This is the code that changed the title up in the tab, inserted into the PHP page template

```
document.title = 'Panhandle Getaways 30A'
```

This is what my header.php looks like

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

Comment: The first code sample is not valid PHP. What is that? Additionally, there is no title attribute for HTML meta tags. It's a title tag like `<title>I am a Page Title</title>`. Your question doesn't makes much sense.

Comment: I'm sorry - the first code is JS. 
I'm trying to overwrite the meta title on one of my Wordpress pages

Comment: So are you wanting to do it client-side or server-side? Again, there is no such thing as meta title in HTML. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp vs https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp

Comment: @trees123 you want to change the meta title specific only one page or the whole site?

Comment: @MonzurAlam Only one page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the meta title to the specific page then you can use the below snippets. You need to put the below code into your theme functions.php & also change your page slug where you can show the meta title.

For test purposes, I use sample page of WordPress.

```
<?php
function wp_meta_title(){
    if( is_page( 'sample-page' ) ){
        return 'Your Meta Title Here....';
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'wp_meta_title', 10 );
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_meta_title', 10 );
```

For better understanding, I also include a screenshot:

[image: WordPress Meta Title change in WordPresss by functionally]

Comment: Thank you. I did this and now I'm getting the name twice up in the browser tab - I am also not seeing the meta tag change though - when I inspect the page I am getting 

<meta property="og:title" content="PMC. Panhandle Getaways | 30A"> 

I would like to remove "PMC." from the beginning of the name, this is the WP page title. We would like to keep it as that in the backend of WP to easily search for it, but wish to get rid of it in the link preview/browser tab

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @MonzurAlam [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74297851/7930986).

If your site uses SEO plugins like Yoast SEO, they might run their own title filters, usually with the default 10 priority. So the fix would be to execute the title change later. In my case setting the priority to 11 was enough.

```
function wp_meta_title(){
    if( is_page( 'sample-page' ) ){
        return 'Your Meta Title Here....';
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'wp_meta_title', 11 );
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'wp_meta_title', 11 );
```